# Rails 6 what does username: <%= ENV.fetch("USERNAME") %> mean in database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Ruby on Rails app, version 6
in my database.yml, there is

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("USERNAME") %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("PASSWORD") %>
  host: localhost
```

but how can I make environment variables?
rails can not get variables from .env file in root
I made .env file but it doesn't work

```
USERNAME=user
PASSWORD=user
```

I don't want to use any other gem because I just want to use rails vanilla grammar..
how can I make envrionment variables???

Comment: .env files do work... if yours isn't there's an issue with your file name / placement or the keys within

Comment: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/01/ruby-environment-variables/

Comment: Usually you need a gem such as "dotenv" or "foreman" in order for the environment variables be loaded onto your computer. Not sure Rails does that automatically. (I have environment variables with foreman and boot foreman with `foreman start -f Procfile.dev -e .env`)

Comment: It depends on your machine, in Windows you go to System Properties Advanced Tab and Environmental Variables Button at the bottom.  You do NOT need a gem to do this. In Linux (or BASH) I found an article that explains it. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-set-environment-variable#:~:text=Set%20an%20Environment%20Variable%20in%20Linux%20Permanently%201,and%20exit%20the%20file.%20...%20More%20items...%20  
In Heroku you can go to you APP, go to the settings  option and then click on Reveal Config Vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using `.env file` and `${USERNAME}` in docker-compose file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read ENV Values from a file, you can put this code in your application.rb.   This is what I use myself in my apps for dev:

```
config.before_configuration do
        env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
        YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
          ENV[key.to_s] = value
        end if File.exists?(env_file)
      end
```

You will make a text file in your config folder called local_env.yml
and put it in this format:

local_env.yml file example:

```
# local_env.yml
# Add account settings and API keys here.
# This file should be listed in .gitignore to keep your settings secret!
# Each entry gets set as a local environment variable.
# This file overrides ENV variables in the Unix shell.
# For example, setting:
# GMAIL_USERNAME: 'Your_Gmail_Username'
# makes 'Your_Gmail_Username' available as ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]

#PRODUCTION LOGGING LEVEL (INFO, DEBUG, UNKNOWN):
LOG_LEVEL: DEBUG

#SERVER SERVE STATIC FILE IN PRODUCTION
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: "TRUE"

# POSTGRESQL DB
FT_DATABASE_USERNAME: 'my db username'
FT_DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'my db password'
```

However Rails 6 or higher has an encrypted variables system for this as well.
It is a little more difficult in my opinion but it is also better in the long run.

https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/10/rails-6-adds-support-for-multi-environment-credentials.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the gem https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

> Shim to load environment variables from .env into ENV in development.